# Nginx: Internal Port Forwarding on Linux server

Tags: python, linux, nginx, portforwarding

I'm currently working on a task which requires port mapping from port A to port B. I'm trying to achieve this by using nginx and as of now no luck.

Here is the scenario, I have a server A which is listening on 123 and it should be redirected internally to 1123 port. There is an another server B which is using python application to communicate with server A port on 123 since it is not a web request nginx configuration is not working. Python application considers ip address and port of the server A when it initiates the communication.

I have tried using Iptables on the linux server A and when I re-ran through the above scenario it worked.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 123 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1123
```

Can you please share your insights on this issue and also suggest me what services can be used apart from Iptables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is a little bit of confusion in your question.

Nginx is not working in your case because it's not a port forwarder, but act as a web proxy, so unless on port 1123 you don't have a web application, it will simply fail. The reason is because nginx works at application level on ISO/OSI model, while iptables works it works at the 3rd and 4th level, it basically receive the packet read the destination port and it remap it.

If you don't want to use iptables as the easiest choice, the range of program you can use is limited to whatever operate in those levels. 
I am not sure that ha-proxy will work even though you can do more things than nginx.

Last option you could try to code something to do the job.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. We discarded this approach as it doesn't work.